# Jbehave with gradle

Tags: bdd, jbehave, junit-jupiter, jbehave-plugin

I am using Gradle in my project to run tests with Jbehave, and here are my dependencies:

```
dependencies {  
    testImplementation "org.jbehave:jbehave-core:4.6.3"
    testImplementation "org.jbehave.site:jbehave-site-resources:3.3.1:@zip"
}
```

I searched on Jbehave website docs and I can't see any support for Gradle tasks, so how I can write a task to run tests with Jbehave and not using any specific plugin for that?